# Is there any different HttpResponse with ClassicHttpResponse?

Tags: java, httpclient

Now I'm using HttpClient library and I wanna download a image.jpg with http connection.
There is a problem.

I can run this code,, but

```
public void run() {
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(imageUrl);
            ClassicHttpResponse response = (ClassicHttpResponse)httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

I can't run this code because I can't get "getEntity()' method.

```
public void run() {
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(imageUrl);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); // this part.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

I wanna get 'getEntity()' method with HttpResponse

Comment: Which library in which version do you use?

Comment: OMG! I add ver.5.1.2. I changed version.(maybe 4.1.2?) 
Now it works well!